# Why does clicking an empty href "shrink" my outlook web add in?

Tags: outlook, office-js

This is part question, part bug report. To reproduce I created a new project "Outlook Web Add In (C#)" in Visual Studio 2017.

Then it generates a default project. In the default project I change:

```
<p class="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-themeDarkAlt ms-fontWeight-semilight">All properties</p>
```

to:

```
<a href="#"><p class="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-themeDarkAlt ms-fontWeight-semilight">All properties</p></a>
```

Now it gets interesting, prior to clicking the newly created link everything looks as expected:

[Prior to clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Wi9.png)

But then when I click the link all of the text in that HTML pane will shrink, more so with each subsequent click:

[After clicking several times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jo2x.png)

No other modifications to the default project were made other than the `<a href="#"> </a>` around any given header tag. It will continue to shrink the more a user clicks.

Although it doesn't solve my question I have also worked around the bug by changing the href statement to the following:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="myfunction(); return false;">
```

My hypothesis is returning false is unexpected by whatever function is causing the content to reduce in size. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: I have seen similar things with Word and Excel add-ins. Not on every computer though. Then, I guessed it was the user using a mouse-pad and his "clicking" involved wrong gesture (zooming). He could not repeat it on demand. He stopped complaining when he started using a real mouse.

Comment: I guess I should add I used a standard mouse, additionally the added "return false" solves the issue as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting, it seems like a bug.

The team is investigating now.

Please track here for update: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/40

*Disclosure: I am working for Microsoft.*